# sending source and medium between chrome extension page

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-analytics

I had created an extension that opens a page from 3 different methods:

1. right click on an image and clicking on the menu item.
2. link I create dynamically on each image.
3. Upload an image in the background pop up.

Once the user clicks on the link or uploads his own image, a new tab is opened with the info of the image he clicked (or uploaded).

I had added the utm_source and utm_campaign to the link but for some reason, the traffic counts as direct traffic and doesn't add the info to the analytics code.

Example url: `chrome-extension://leoaaeofnhfjkmghbdngecpnadnolnnj/index.html?utm_source=extension&utm_medium=upload#data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/`

Other then that issue, tracking is working correctly (sending pageview and events).

Anyone experienced this issue and have a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

After a long investigation I had found a solution:

First, we get the URL params:

```
var url_string = window.location;
var url = new URL(url_string);
var utm_source = url.searchParams.get("utm_source");
var utm_medium = url.searchParams.get("utm_medium");
```

Then we make sure to count own domain as referrer:

```
ga('create', 'UA-xxx-x', 'auto',{'alwaysSendReferrer': true});
```

And finally we set the source and medium manually before calling for the page view event:

```
ga('set', 'campaignSource', utm_source);
ga('set', 'campaignMedium', utm_medium);
ga('send', 'pageview', '/xxx.html');
```

I'm guessing that as the protocol is chrome-extension:// the utm params doesn't handle correctly and also as the referral is the same domain (extension id) it doesn't count as a referral.

Hope this will help someone...